# xquery to get plain text-element having MD5

Tags: xquery, basex

I have implemented a client-server based app where each client is represented by a PLAIN-TEXT email (since i have to interact with users via email sometimes)

The client sends its email as md5-encoded string (weakness of md5 is another topic but not relevant for the question.

I am searching for a xquery-statement to retrieve the plain-text from the xml doc, having its encryption.

In SQL it would be something like `select * from db where MD5(db.email)==email`

Comment: Are you sure about [tag:xbase]? I don't see it is related to XQuery. Did you mean [tag:basex]?

Comment: OUUU yes you are right.. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

BaseX has a [`hash:` XQuery module](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Hashing_Module), which also contains an MD5 function [`hash:md5($value as xs:anyAtomicType) as xs:base64Binary`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Hashing_Module#hash:md5).

Your query will be something similar to `//user[@email eq hash:md5($email)]`.

Comment: thank you. How do i define the variable $email? is'nt 'eq' to compare single values? $email is a sequence... do I need a loop?

Comment: This is just an example. You did not provide any further details on your context, so I just put something together to showcase the general usage. You can of course also use `=` if it fits your task.